# How to use a css grid in Vaadin Flow as replacement for Framework 8's GridLayout?

Tags: css, vaadin10

I'm trying to migrate an existing Vaadin 8 application to Vaadin 12 and need to know how to recreate the functionality of Vaadin 8's GridLayout in Vaadin 12.

According to [Vaadin Docs](https://vaadin.com/docs/v10/flow/migration/5-components.html#layouts) a GridLayout can be replaced in Vaadin 12 by: 
*"Use Div together with the new CSS Grid functionality that is supported in most browsers"*

Unfortunately it's not totally clear how exactly this can be done.

Lets assume that I have a Vaadin composite *"HelloGrid"*:

```
@StyleSheet("styles/hello-grid.css")
public class HelloGrid extends Composite<Div> {

   public HelloGrid(){

     // EDIT: This line is my solution to the question
     getElement().getClassList().add("hello-grid");

     Label labelOne = new Label();
     labelOne.addClassName("label-one");

     Label labelTwo = new Label();
     labelTwo.addClassName("label-two");

     add(labelOne);
     add(labelTwo);
   }
}
```

And a css file *"hello-grid.css"*:

```
.hello-grid {
    display: grid !important;
    grid-template-rows: auto;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
}

.label-one {
    grid-column: 1;
}

.label-two {
    grid-column: 2;
}
```

- How can I associate the *".hello-grid"* css class with the HelloGrid Composite.
- Is this the right/preferred way to use a css grid in Vaadin 12 at all

Comment: Meanwhile I found a possible solution by myself: add `getElement().getClassList().add("hello-grid");` to the constructor of the Composite.
But I initially expected to be able to set the elements classname by an annotation instead. I'll edit my question with this solution.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bit too late, but maybe answers someone else question.

It depends where exactly you have placed your `css` styles. I would suggest to place under `webapp\frontend\styles`, then you would be able to access them using `@StyleSheet("frontend://styles/hello-grid.css")`. As it also noted in official documentation, here [Including Style Sheets](https://vaadin.com/docs/v13/flow/importing-dependencies/tutorial-include-css.html) it's

> Relative to Servlet URL

Using your example with this set-up: [image: Style's file location]

and styles like those (basically just adding colors to your stylesheet to verify, it works ) [image: Style's file contant]

this was the output:
[image]

I haven't found any exact guides on Vaadin page, how you could use Grid styles, but this tutorial looks quite promising [A Complete Guide to Grid](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/complete-guide-grid/). Otherwise, there shouldn't be anything special regarding Vaadin.

Also, it seems that there is an add-on in directory, which might help [Css Grid Layout](https://vaadin.com/directory/component/css-grid-layout) (Through, I haven't tried it out myself)